# Loop through all bindings configured in IIS with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis-7

I'm looking for a way to go through all *binding settings* already configured in my IIS.

Im using this to work with the IIS in Powershell:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

So far I was able to get the main required information i want:

```
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
```

My array $Websites is filled correctly and with the following command...

```
$Websites[2]
```

..I recieve this result:

```
Name         ID   State    Physical Path       Bindings    
----         --   -----    -------------       --------------     
WebPage3      5            D:\Web\Page3        http  *:80:WebPage3  
                                               https *:443:WebPage3
```

Now here's the part I having a hard time with:

I want to check if the binding is correct. In order to do that I *only* need the binding. I tried:

```
foreach ($site in $Websites)
{
    $site = $Websites[0]
    $site | select-string "http"
}
```

Debugging that code shows me that $Site doesn't contain what I expected: "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement". I currently have no clue how to explicitly get to the binding information in order to to something like this (inside the foreach loop):

```
 if ($site.name -eq "WebPage3" -and $site.Port -eq "80") {
    #website is ok    
 } 
 else {
    #remove all current binding
    #add correct binding
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

---

Solution:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {

    $Binding = $Site.bindings
    [string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection
    [string]$IP = $BindingInfo.SubString($BindingInfo.IndexOf(" "),$BindingInfo.IndexOf(":")-$BindingInfo.IndexOf(" "))         
    [string]$Port = $BindingInfo.SubString($BindingInfo.IndexOf(":")+1,$BindingInfo.LastIndexOf(":")-$BindingInfo.IndexOf(":")-1) 

    Write-Host "Binding info for" $Site.name " - IP:"$IP", Port:"$Port

    if ($Site.enabledProtocols -eq "http") {
        #DO CHECKS HERE     
    }
    elseif($site.enabledProtocols -eq "https") {
        #DO CHECKS HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `get-webbinding`, `remove-webbinding` and `new-webbinding`?

Comment: Welcome. I've removed my answer because I received a downvote (probably something wrong there) but you can work fine with the standard cmdlets. Also remove-webbinding and new-webbinding work fine.

Comment: If you just want to view or list all the bindings try this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35158534/4502867

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but I will try. I see that you reference `$Websites[2]` which is *webPage3*.
You can do it like this:

```
$site = $websites | Where-object { $_.Name -eq 'WebPage3' }
```

Then when you look at `$site.Bindings`, you will realize that you need the `Collection` member:

```
$site.bindings.Collection
```

On my machine this returns this:

```
protocol                       bindingInformation
--------                       ------------------
http                           *:80:
net.tcp                        808:*
net.pipe                       *
net.msmq                       localhost
msmq.formatname                localhost
https                          *:443:
```

And the test might then look like this:

```
$is80 = [bool]($site.bindings.Collection | ? { $_.bindingInformation -eq '*:80:' })
if ($is80) {
    #website is ok    
} else {
    #remove all current binding
    #add correct binding
 }
```

I sent content of `Collection` to pipeline and filtere only objects where property `bindingInformation` is equal to desired value (change it). Then I cast it to `[bool]`. This will return `$true` if there is desired item, `$false` otherwise.

Comment: $site.bindings.Collection and $_.bindingInformation was what i was looking for! The bool-methode works, but i'd prefer to check it as edited in my Post.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if there were multiple bindings on a site then if I needed to script access to individual parts of the bindings otherwise I only got the first binding.  To get them all I needed the script to be extended as below:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites

foreach ($Site in $Websites) {

    $Binding = $Site.bindings

    [string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection

    [string[]]$Bindings = $BindingInfo.Split(" ")

    $i = 0
    $header = ""
    Do{
        Write-Output ("Site    :- " + $Site.name + " <" + $Site.id +">")

        Write-Output ("Protocol:- " + $Bindings[($i)])

        [string[]]$Bindings2 = $Bindings[($i+1)].Split(":")

        Write-Output ("IP      :- " + $Bindings2[0])
        Write-Output ("Port    :- " + $Bindings2[1])
        Write-Output ("Header  :- " + $Bindings2[2])

        $i=$i+2
    } while ($i -lt ($bindings.count))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar to the last answer, but this corrects to HTTPS sites and adds a bit more information that is useful.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$hostname = hostname
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
    $Binding = $Site.bindings
    [string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection
    [string[]]$Bindings = $BindingInfo.Split(" ")#[0]
    $i = 0
    $status = $site.state
    $path = $site.PhysicalPath
    $fullName = $site.name
    $state = ($site.name -split "-")[0]
    $Collection = ($site.name -split "-")[1]
    $status = $site.State
    $anon = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\sites -Location $site.name | select-object Value
    $basic = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/BasicAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\ -location $site.name | select-object Value
    Do{
        if( $Bindings[($i)] -notlike "sslFlags=*"){
            [string[]]$Bindings2 = $Bindings[($i+1)].Split(":")
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member Date $Date
            $obj | Add-Member Host $hostname
            $obj | Add-Member State $state
            $obj | Add-Member Collection $Collection
            $obj | Add-Member SiteName $Site.name
            $obj | Add-Member SiteID $site.id
            $obj | Add-member Path $site.physicalPath
            $obj | Add-Member Protocol $Bindings[($i)]
            $obj | Add-Member Port $Bindings2[1]
            $obj | Add-Member Header $Bindings2[2]
            $obj | Add-member AuthAnon $Anon.value
            $obj | Add-member AuthBasic $basic.value
            $obj | Add-member Status $status
            $obj #take this out if you want to save to csv| export-csv "c:\temp\$date-$hostname.csv" -Append -notypeinformation
            $i=$i+2
        }
        else{$i=$i+1}
    } while ($i -lt ($bindings.count))
}
```