# Search in bindings with get-website?

Tags: iis, powershell

Why can't I do a simple:

```
Get-Website | where { $_.Bindings -like "*DOMAIN*" }
```

On the Bindings? But it works fine on the Name and Physical Path?
Any way to do a search on the Bindings with get-website?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6188254/763026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there can be multiple bindings.  You have to iterate through each of them:

```
Get-Website | 
    Select-Object Bindings |
    Where { $_.BindingInformation -like '*DOMAIN*' }
```