# Display all sites and bindings in PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell, powershell-3.0, iis-8

I am documenting all the sites and binding related to the site from the IIS. Is there an easy way to get this list through a PowerShell script rather than manually typing looking at IIS?

I want the output to be something like this:

```
Site                          Bindings
TestSite                     www.hello.com
                             www.test.com
JonDoeSite                   www.johndoe.site
```

Comment: what version of Windows/IIS do you have? With IIS on Windows Server 2012 you can simply use `Get-WebBinding` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes it is Server 2012. Running Get-Webbinding returns protocal, bindinginformaiton, sslFlags. not in same format as i want my output.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try something like this to get the format you wanted:

```
Get-WebBinding | % {
    $name = $_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1'
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name = $name
        Binding = $_.bindinginformation.Split(":")[-1]
    }
} | Group-Object -Property Name | 
Format-Table Name, @{n="Bindings";e={$_.Group.Binding -join "`n"}} -Wrap
```

Comment: Very nice. I would not have thought to add regex to evaluate the objects, but that's very good use of the New\Group-Object cmdlets. I will have to update some code in light of that.

Comment: Using powershell.exe to call myscript.ps1, Format-Table not working to display (output)

Comment: In Windows 2008 R2 SP1, this throws error _"The term 'Get-WebBinding' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."_ (the second answer below works if mildly changed).

Comment: It's already mentioned in the first comment on the question :)

Comment: Awesome Script only one thing have to do. We have to run powershell as administrator

Answer (score 107):

Try this:

```
Import-Module Webadministration
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites
```

It should return something that looks like this:

```
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
ChristophersWeb 22   Started    C:\temp             http *:8080:ChristophersWebsite.ChDom.com
```

From here you can refine results, but be careful. A pipe to the select statement will not give you what you need. Based on your requirements I would build a custom object or hashtable.

Comment: how does it work? I mean it works but no matter where i have my files located? the IIS:\Sites will always pick items from IIS? or is that bound to a spec. path ?

Comment: @RayofCommand - this works by parsing out the location defined in the IIS web configuration files, the ones that replaced the IIS 5/6 Metabase. These are xml files by nature and are found in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: At least in Windows 2008 R2 SP1 you must first call `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or the _Import-Module_ will not work. And you need to put the argument in quotes, like this: `Get-ChildItem -Path "IIS:\Sites"`, or you'll receive a syntax error.

Comment: That should not occur, the module is signed. I'll research that. @Abel

Comment: I get an error that says `Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.` when I try to run the above command. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: @RyanGates When you run Import-Module WebAdministration does it throw an error? This module should add the IIS PS provider to your session. Ensure you're running as an administrator as well.

Comment: `Get-Website` does essentially the same thing and is a bit shorter.

Comment: Just want to add a note that this does not work with older version of powershell.  command "Get-Host | Select-Object Version" returns "1.0.0.0"  Running the PS C:\Windows\System32> Import-Module Webadmininstration
The term 'Import-Module' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable prog
ram, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module  <<<< Webadmininstrationimport command fails right away is a good indicator.

Answer (score 32):

If you just want to list all the sites (ie. to find a binding)

Change the working directory to "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv"

**cd c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv**

Next run "appcmd list sites" (plural) and output to a file.  e.g c:\IISSiteBindings.txt

**appcmd list sites > c:\IISSiteBindings.txt**

Now open with notepad from your command prompt.

**notepad c:\IISSiteBindings.txt**

Comment: Not a PS answer; but short and sweet and also lists ID numbers which can be useful for scanning IIS logs.

Comment: This is the best answer for those running a very old version of Windows Server.  Windows server 6.0 (Build 6003: Service Pack 2). Keep in mind that you might need to start command prompt with Administration access.

Comment: As a one liner: `c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites`

Answer (score 28):

The most easy way as I saw:

```
Foreach ($Site in get-website) { Foreach ($Bind in $Site.bindings.collection) {[pscustomobject]@{name=$Site.name;Protocol=$Bind.Protocol;Bindings=$Bind.BindingInformation}}}
```

Comment: Great solution, Alexander!, I just added physicalPath: `Foreach ($Site in get-website)
{ Foreach ($Bind in $Site.bindings.collection)
{ [pscustomobject]@{name=$Site.name;Protocol=$Bind.Protocol;Bindings=$Bind.BindingInformation;
  path=$Site.physicalPath
}}}`

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. You may need to **Run Powershell as Administrator** for this script to execute, else you might get an error that **you should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function DisplayLocalSites
{

try{

Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted

$list = @()
foreach ($webapp in get-childitem IIS:\Sites\)
{
    $name = "IIS:\Sites\" + $webapp.name
    $item = @{}

$item.WebAppName = $webapp.name

foreach($Bind in $webapp.Bindings.collection)
{
    $item.SiteUrl = $Bind.Protocol +'://'+         $Bind.BindingInformation.Split(":")[-1]
}


$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item
$list += $obj
}

$list | Format-Table -a -Property "WebAppName","SiteUrl"

$list | Out-File -filepath C:\websites.txt

Set-ExecutionPolicy restricted

}
catch
{
$ExceptionMessage = "Error in Line: " + $_.Exception.Line + ". " +     $_.Exception.GetType().FullName + ": " + $_.Exception.Message + " Stacktrace: "    + $_.Exception.StackTrace
$ExceptionMessage
}
}
```

Comment: this one only shows my first domain in each IIS:\Sites\ and not all other domain name bindings i configured within the same site.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Get-ADDWebBindings {
param([string]$Name="*",[switch]$http,[switch]$https)
    try {
    if (-not (Get-Module WebAdministration)) { Import-Module WebAdministration }
    Get-WebBinding | ForEach-Object { $_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1' } | Sort | Get-Unique | Where-Object {$_ -like $Name} | ForEach-Object {
        $n=$_
        Get-WebBinding | Where-Object { ($_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1') -like $n } | ForEach-Object {
            if ($http -or $https) {
                if ( ($http -and ($_.protocol -like "http")) -or ($https -and ($_.protocol -like "https")) ) {
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{Name = $n;Protocol=$_.protocol;Binding = $_.bindinginformation}
                }
            } else {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{Name = $n;Protocol=$_.protocol;Binding = $_.bindinginformation}
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch {
       $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this page because I needed to migrate a site with many many bindings to a new server. I used some of the code here to generate the powershell script below to add the bindings to the new server. Sharing in case it is useful to someone else:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$site = $Websites | Where-object { $_.Name -eq 'site-name-in-iis-here' }

$Binding = $Site.bindings
[string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection
[string[]]$Bindings = $BindingInfo.Split(" ")
$i = 0
$header = ""
Do{
    [string[]]$Bindings2 = $Bindings[($i+1)].Split(":")

    Write-Output ("New-WebBinding -Name `"site-name-in-iis-here`" -IPAddress " + $Bindings2[0] + " -Port " + $Bindings2[1] + " -HostHeader `"" + $Bindings2[2] + "`"")

    $i=$i+2
} while ($i -lt ($bindings.count))
```

It generates records that look like this:

```
New-WebBinding -Name "site-name-in-iis-here" -IPAddress "*" -Port 80 -HostHeader www.aaa.com
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update IIS 10.0+ (2017+)

You can use the newer [`IISAdministration`](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery) module with the [`Get-IISSite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlet like this:

```
PS> Import-Module IISAdministration
PS> Get-IISSite

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Started    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80: 
PattiFul         2    Stopped    C:\inetpub\PattiFul            http *:8080: 
                                                                http *:8033: 
FTPSite          3               C:\inetpub\ftproot             ftp *:21: 
DavidChe         4    Started    c:\                            http *:8088: 
MyNewSite        6555 Started    C:\inetpub\wwwroot             http *:8099: 
                                                                http *:8022:
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I wanted to generate a web page with links to all the websites running on my IIS instance. I used [Alexander Shapkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113479/740639) to come up with the following to generate a bunch of links.

```
$hostname = "localhost"

Foreach ($Site in get-website) {
    Foreach ($Bind in $Site.bindings.collection) {
        $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
            name=$Site.name;
            Protocol=$Bind.Protocol;
            Bindings=$Bind.BindingInformation
        }
        $data.Bindings = $data.Bindings -replace '(:$)', ''
        $html = "<a href=""" + $data.Protocol + "://" + $data.Bindings + """>" + $data.name + "</a>"
        $html.Replace("*", $hostname);
    }
}
```

Then I paste the results into this hastily written HTML:

```
<html>
<style>
    a { display: block; }
</style>
{paste PowerShell results here}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose I could probably include the HTML in the script, and dispense with the pasting.