# Use Chef to modify settings for all IIS sites running on a node

Tags: iis, chef-infra

our ops team wants to make sure that all IIS web sites are (a) logging to the right place and (b) logging the right things.  The most awesome [IIS Cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis) allows me to do both of these things *if* I know what sites are running on this old box, which, sadly, I do not.  So a fairly straightforward implementation *could* be:

```
list_of_sites.each do |s|
  iis_site s do
    log_directory 'c:/fireplace'
    etc.
  end
end
```

But ... I don't know what sites are running on a given node.  Ohai doesn't seem to have this info, but maybe there is a wonderous (I like this spelling better) Ohai plugin that my google-foo couldn't find. I could write an ohai plugin for this I suppose.  But it would be my first so a little reluctant to go there.  Are there other options?

Good list of ways to list sites is here: [Display all sites and bindings in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528492/display-all-sites-and-bindings-in-powershell), but not sure how to use a list of sites generated by powershell from within a recipe.

We're running chef 12 and various IIS's but oldest is 7.0.

Thx for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Making an Ohai plugin for this one thing is probably overkill, I would just use `powershell_out` with a variant of the code you linked to. You would want something like this:

```
cmd = powershell_out!(<<-EOH)
# A bunch of PS code goes here
EOH
sites = some_kind_of_parsing(cmd.stdout)
sites.each do |site|
```

The example PS code you linked is using `Format-Table` which would suck to parse back out, but I bet you can find some way to output it as JSON which would be much easier, or even just a line-based table without the header lines.