# Can I get a complete list of all HTTP bindings on an IIS Server?

Tags: iis, https

In changing the SSL certificate in an HTTPS binding on an IIS website, I choose the new certificate, and then get the following message:

***"At least one other site is using the same binding and the binding is configured with a different certificate.  Are you sure that you want to reuse this HTTP binding and reassign the other site or sites to use the new certificate?"***

This sounds ominously like it's going to DO something to the other site.  Maybe several or even many other sites since they all use the same certificate.

There are hundreds of sites on this IIS server.  I'd hate to have to go through them one at a time looking at bindings.

Is there a way to get a list of all HTTP bindings for all sites on the server so I can find whichever other site it is that is using this certificate?

Comment: Might be duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528492/display-all-sites-and-bindings-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Import-Module Webadministration
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites
```

WebAdministration module will allow you to interact with IIS as well as a hierarchical view of the IIS installation.